# Fuzzy query, return specific term in whole the field

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm doing this query to my elasticsearch server:

```
{
    "query": {
        "multi_match" : {
            "query" : "Onions",
            "fields": ["title_en", "description_en"],
            "fuzziness": "5"
        }
    },
    "_source": ["title_en", "description_en", "active", "id"],
    "size": 25
}
```

and it is working good, the result is:

```
{
    "took": 15,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 10,
        "successful": 10,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 2,
        "max_score": 0.99976414,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "fmf",
                "_type": "menu",
                "_id": "18",
                "_score": 0.99976414,
                "_source": {
                    "description_en": "Delicious onions rings, the best flavors",
                    "active": true,
                    "title_en": "Onions rings",
                    "id": 18
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "fmf",
                "_type": "menu",
                "_id": "16",
                "_score": 0.574256,
                "_source": {
                    "description_en": "A delectable array of our most popular starters that’s big enough to share. Served with different sauces for mixing and matching. Includes Onion Rings, Potato Skins, Tomato Bruschetta and Santa Fe Spring Rolls",
                    "active": true,
                    "title_en": "Jumbo combo veg",
                    "id": 16
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

As you can see, the result found is `description_en` and return whole the field, but exist a way to return only the found word?
Like, if I search for honyons (bad written), return only "Onion" instead all the field ???

Comment: you can take a look at highlight feature of elastic. that might solve your purpose.

Comment: A fuzziness of 5 is not possible, it's either AUTO, 0, 1 or 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggest API seems to be what you're looking for, in particular the [term suggester](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-term.html).

I agree with comment, [highlighting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html) might be a solution.

By the way, a [fuzziness](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#fuzziness) of 5 is not possible, it's either AUTO, 0, 1 or 2.